# Maven failsafe run Fitnesse tests

Tags: java, maven, fitnesse, maven-failsafe-plugin, fitnesse-slim

I need to run some Fitnesse tests on the maven integration phase, when I do  `mvn clean verify`  the Fitnesse tests are executed but after the execution I get this:

> Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.723
>   sec - in integration.runnerIT [INFO] --------------------- [INFO]
>   BUILD SUCCESS [INFO] ---------------------

The thing is that the tests are executed and one of the test fail but maven says that no test was executed.

This is my pom file:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>

            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <excludes>
                <!-- this test actually runs fitnesse tests
                     therefore it will only be executed for
                     integration-test goal
                -->
                <exclude>**/*IT.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>

        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*Test.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>


    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
            <encoding>UTF8</encoding>
            <optimize>true</optimize>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

And this is my Test runner:

```
@RunWith(FitNesseRunner.class)
@FitNesseRunner.Suite("TimTests")
@FitNesseRunner.FitnesseDir("./src/test/resources")
@FitNesseRunner.OutputDir("./target/fitnesse-results")
public class runnerIT {
}
```

How maven can show the number of Fitness tests are executed and if they failed or not? is it possible?

Comment: It is possible, I use it all the time, but I have customized my runner and use a custom listener. What happens when you explicitly call `mvn clean test-compile failsafe:integration-test`?

Comment: Are you running a single test page, or a suite? Does this make a difference in the observed behavior?

Comment: Right now im running only one test but in the future I will execute more

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, for me it just reports the tests run and the number of failures, if any. Which version of FitNesse and jUnit are you using?